# Creating buttons with links using CakePHP's HTML/Form Helpers

Tags: cakephp

I would like to convert a link into a button using CakePHP Helpers.

With `$this->Html->link()` I am able to use an array() to include `'action' => 'view' . $user['User']['id']`, but I am not sure how to include this when using `$this->Form->button()` instead.

Using `$this->Html->link()`:

```
$this->Html->link('Click me', array(
    'controller' => 'users',
    'action' => 'view' . $user['User']['id']));
```

### My Solutions

My solutions do not allow me to add `'action' => 'view' . $user['User']['id']`

Using `$this->Form->button()`:

```
echo $this->Form->button('Click me', array(
    'type' => 'button',
    'onclick' => 'location.href=\'/rentmyride/users/index/\';',
    ));
```

Using `<input>` tag:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Click me" 
    onclick="location.href='http://www.domain.com';">
```

Using `<button>` tag:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="location.href='http://www.domain.com';">
    Click me
</button>
```

Comment: changing a link to a button with a onclick? Sounds like you really want to style your link as a button - which is something you should do with css alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML5 buttons have a formaction attribute for this use. Of course this works only in modern browsers

```
$this->Form->button(
    'Click me', 
    array(
        'formaction' => Router::url(
            array('controller' => 'users','action' => 'view' . $user['User']['id'])
         )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are using cakephp 2.X and above please use this line of code for link in button:

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'Users', 'action'=>'admin_index'))?>'">;Go Back</button>;
```

I hope this is works for you