# 'formnovalidate' not working CakePHP 3

Tags: php, html, validation, cakephp, button

I'am using CakePHP 3 and I need two buttons in the same form, one for cancel and other to send the data, to achieve this I set an specific name to the cancel button and look for it in the controller when the data is received via `POST`.

My view looks like:

```
<div class="pacientes form large-9 medium-8 columns content">
    <?= $this->Form->create($variable) ?>
    <fieldset>
        // Some inputs
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__d('menu', 'send')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__d('menu', 'cancel'), ['name' => 'cancelSubmit']) ?>    
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>    
</div>
```

The controller relevant code:

```
public function add()
{
    // Some code
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if(isset($this->request->data['cancelSubmit'])){
            return $this->redirect($this->referer());
        }            
        // More code
    }
    // A bit more code
}
```

The problem comes with the validation, if the form has some required inputs the cancel button doesn't work because it triggers the form validation and shows a message telling that the field can't be empty.

I tried adding the

```
`formnovalidate` => true
```

option (as said in the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html)) to the `cancel` button in many ways but it doesn't work.

The goal is to have the submit button to send the data (with validation) and the cancel button to return to the previous page (without validation). Anyone know how to do this and why 'formnovalidate' doesnt' work? Am I doing anything wrong?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than having the cancel button submit the form, you could just have it be a link to the page that you want to redirect to.

Comment: Yes I know, but I would like to add it as a button, I don't think this can't be achieved

Comment: You can definitely make a button a link.  Check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20740668/creating-buttons-with-links-using-cakephps-html-form-helpers

Comment: Or even simpler would be to just add a link and define `'class' => 'button'`
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#creating-links

Comment: If you're using bootstrap then you can have a link look exactly like a button by adding the bootstrap classes to the element

Comment: Thank you both. The link with the button class fits my requirements.